# Two IncrementalLoadingCollection on one viewmodel

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I have `Pivot` with two `PivotItems`.
On each `PivotItem` I have `ListView` with different `ItemsSources`.

Fist `ListView` have this binding:

```
Items = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<MainPageViewModel, Item>(this, 5);

public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        *here network request*
        return itemsList;
    }
```

IncrementalLoadingCollection - collection from UWPCommunityToolkit
How can I implement same **Items2** = new IncrementalLoadingCollection(this, 5);
with different network logic on same VM?

Comment: If you look at the sample and the docs of the uwp incremental loading https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/Incremental%20Loading%20Collection/IncrementalLoadingCollectionPage.xaml.cs you will see they use a separate Source object that is use to bind to list views and it has it's own network handling. So you'll need 2 of those sources

Comment: Both sources one same VM. Items = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<MainPageViewModel, Item>(**this**, 5); I can't create separate class with source. VM contain injected properties for access to network.

Comment: If you use dependency injection you could just inject the network access in the separate sources too

Comment: IncrementalLoadingCollection source class must be parameterless

Comment: Not saying it has to be constructor injection... depending on the ioc you are using you should be able to request a needed interface in code, not as method param